# Did you erase the comments pointing out that Wagner is a terrorist organization?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, comments

Were my comments to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80037/can-the-crimes-of-mercenary-groups-such-as-wagner-be-attributed-to-the-countries), pointing out that comparisons between Blackwater and Wagner are entirely inappropriate get erased?  *Those were my reasons for voting to close the question*, which is an appropriate use of comments.

This is a push question trying to whitewash Wagner by claiming that other countries have similar organization, but the only other country that has a similar organization is Iran, which sponsors Hezbollah (the militant wing, not the political one).

**Wagner is a designated terrorist organization.**  This isn't just my opinion.  This has been affirmed by [France](https://www.politico.eu/article/pre-write-french-parliament-designates-wagner-a-terrorist-group/) and the [UK](https://www.reuters.com/world/uk/britain-set-blacklist-russias-wagner-group-the-times-2023-05-09/).  It is deemed to be a "[transnational criminal organization](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/wagner-group-russia-ukraine-putin-prigozhin-1.6729177)" by the US (and not because it's a PMC... the US does not consider PMCs to be criminal as such).

While **Blackwater had [incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisour_Square_massacre) of trigger-happy defensive actions** which lead to unnecessary civilian casualties, it is RIDICULOUS to compare it to Wagner. **Wagner, as its modus operandi, has engaged in perfidy; torture, maiming, and deliberate killing of civilians and PoWs; other war crimes.**

If there were flags indicating that my comments were too eager, please, be mindful of the fact that this site is clearly a target of some degree of Russian war-time propaganda designed to whitewash Russian atrocities.  So unless there is a clear case of people being out of line, extreme statements made against the Russian army during this war are often justified (and factual) because of the extreme circumstances.

Until the claim (that Blackwater and Wagner are similar) is properly addressed, the comments, pointing out that they are not similar, should not be deleted.

---

---

---

**Edit**

## What is "Constructive Criticism?"

**There appears to be a misunderstanding about what is "constructive criticism."**  This is clearly demonstrated by the answer to this question calling the erased comments "not constructive" even though **they were a textbook example of constructive criticism**.

For the benefit of everyone, it's probably good to review what is "constructive criticism," then.
There is the [dictionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/constructive_criticism):

> Noun
>
> constructive criticism
>
> 1. Criticism intended to provide suggestions for improvement without insulting the recipient.

And there is the [less abstract definition](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/constructive-criticism) from Indeed, intended to both explain what it is and how to engage in it:

> Constructive criticism is feedback that provides specific, **actionable suggestions**. Rather than providing general advice, constructive criticism gives specific recommendations on how to make positive improvements. Constructive criticism is clear, to the point and **easy to put into action**.

1. A particular type of an "actionable suggestion" is suggesting an alternative.
2. Another particular type of an "actionable suggestion" is suggesting an addition to what has already been written.

The latter one is sometimes known as "**yes, *and***".  Because it doesn't take anything away from the already existing work and only adds.  This is generally considered preferable.

Unfortunately, the latter type is not always possible.

When one has to state that some part must be replaced with another
in order to create an improvement, that's suggesting an alternative and it's not a "yes, and" suggestion.

---

---

**Here's an example of the 1st kind of constructive criticism:**

Original Sentence:
"The conclusion of the research paper *lacks sufficient evidence to support the claim.*"

Constructive Criticism with an Alternative:
"The conclusion of the research paper *could be strengthened by providing more concrete examples and citing specific studies or data to bolster the claim.*"

**Here's an example of the 2st kind of constructive criticism (aka "yes, and"):**

Original Statement:
"The team's project proposal was well-organized and covered all the essential points."

"Yes, and" Constructive Criticism: "The team's project proposal was well-organized and covered all the essential points.  *To further enhance its impact, consider incorporating real-life examples or case studies to illustrate the practical applications of the proposed ideas*."

---

---

---

## So now that we know what constructive criticism is, why were my comments "constructive?"

Well, because mentioning Blackwater (at all) made the question weaker.  Simply removing it, and making Wagner the sole example, would have strengthened it.

It would have avoided the problem of appearing to draw an equivalence between Blackwater and Wagner (and this appearance was the problem which I mentioned).  And it **would still preserve the essential inquiry part of the question**: "do the countries employing mercs bare responsibility for the crimes those mercs commit."

In other words, my comments, were in fact suggesting an alternative which would have strengthened the question.  So they were constructive.

Comment: The question only states that Blackwater and Wagner are both mercenary groups. It makes no further comparisons or claims of similarity. Though if you want to play that game, [Blackwater aren't exactly squeaky clean themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisour_Square_massacre).

Comment: @F1Krazy I didn't say they were squeaky clean.  In fact I alluded to the linked even, both in the erased comment and in this question.  But comparing trigger-happy guards to a terrorist group, with a history of terror as its MO, comes very close to giving the terrorist group a pass.  Wagner is as bad ISIS, maybe worse, in their methods

Comment: Wagner is a terrorist organization, who told you that? Définition of terrorist organization should not be used as it's very biased. For example hizboullah is considered terrorist organization by the US, where it's just another political party in Lebanon. Also other countries may consider black water private army as terrorist and it also true depending on who you are

Answer (score 7):

I removed your comments because they were not constructive.

Justified or not, your polemic about Wagner and their warcrimes did not add anything productive to the question. That question is certainly not "Russian war-time propaganda designed to whitewash Russian atrocities". It is asking a question about warcrimes committed by private military contractors **in general**, using Wagner as an example. It is doing that in a factual and objective tone that should be the norm in this community.

For more information on how comments on questions should and should not be used, please review [the help center article on the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is incorrect.  The comments were constructive.  **Constructive criticism is criticism which offers alternative approaches**.  There was nothing polemic about my statements.  Wagner's history of terror is documented, well-known, and recognized as such by more than 1 government.  Discussing trigger happy guards, who ended up killing civilians, in the same breath as international terrorists, whose main MO is terrorism and going outside of any accepted norms of war, amounts to giving a pass to the terrorists.  The comments gave my reason for VTC, which is an acceptable use of comments.

Comment: The fact that I clearly stated I thought it an unacceptable comparison made the comments *constructive* because it suggested that the question would be improved by not having that comparison.  *Even if you don't agree with the content* of the comment, you cannot say that *its manner was* not *constructive* because it suggested an alternative.